# Script Tags Loading Out of Order in Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

I am building a bare-bones jsfiddle/codepen clone.

The user I able to type in HTML, CSS, and JS and the code is sent to an iframe an rendered there. In addition, the code editor will have Three.js loaded so the user can make use of it. So I load three.js into the iframe with a `script` tag by default and then a second `script` tag for whatever the user inputs.

So the user should have access to `THREE`. If the user opens the Viewer component (ie causes it to render by clicking on the UI tab that opens it) before attempting to input any JS, it works fine. 
But if the user tries to input JS say `console.log(THREE)` before opening the viewer tab it does not.

I have two questions: (1) obviously if I could force the `Viewer` to initialize before it is shown for the first time this would solve the problem. Is there anyway to do something like that? (2) My understanding was that `script` tags load synchronously. So because I append the three script and then the user script, shouldn't it load the three script completely and then when it gets to the user script `THREE` is available to it? *(3)* Can I pre-populate the `iframe` DOM with a `script` tag that's there from the start?

I tried to log out the contents of my iframe `document.body` to see what is going on and it seems that both the scripts are in the DOM before I make the first `appendChild` call. Perhaps this is some weird async Chrome console behavior I'm not familiar with though.

I am trying to understand what's happening here and work out how I can get these scripts to load/execute in order.

Viewer.js (the majority of the relevant code in this file:

```
class Viewer extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this._updateIframe();
  }
  componentDidUpdate() {
    this._updateIframe();
  }
  _updateIframe() {
    const iframe = this.refs.iframe;
    const document = iframe.contentDocument;
    const head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    document.body.innerHTML = this.props.html;

    const style = document.createElement('style');
    style.rel = 'stylesheet';
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.innerHTML = this.props.css;
    head.appendChild(style);

    const three = document.createElement('script');
    three.type = 'text/javascript';
    three.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/90/three.min.js';
    console.log('document.body before adding three', document.body);
    document.body.appendChild(three);
    console.log('document.body after adding three', document.body);

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.text = this.props.js;
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    console.log('document.body after adding script', document.body);
  }
  render() {
    return <iframe ref="iframe" />
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({ ...state.sourceCode }); 
const mapDispatchToProps = {};
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps, 
  mapDispatchToProps
) (Viewer);
```

[image: Console output]

File.js:

```
class File extends React.Component {
  onChange = (value) => {
    this.props.updateSourceCode(value, this.props.fileType);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <AceEditor
        mode={ this.props.fileType }
        theme="github"
        onChange={this.onChange}
        name="UNIQUE_ID_OF_DIV"
        editorProps={{ $blockScrolling: true }}
      />
    );
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = () => ({});
const mapDispatchToProps = {
  updateSourceCode
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(File);
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className='app'>
        <Tabs type="card">
          <TabPane
            tab='HTML'
            key='1'
          >
            <File fileType='html' />
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane
            tab='CSS'
            key='2'
          >
            <File fileType='css' />
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane
            tab='JavaScript'
            key='3'
          >
            <File fileType='js' />
          </TabPane>
          <TabPane
            tab='Viewer'
            key='4'
          >
            <Viewer />
          </TabPane>
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `<script>` loaded using javascript load asyncrhonously i.e like `<script async src=....>` does that help? Hmm, though it looks like you're loading one script using `src` and the other is "inline" - and async makes no effect on inline script ... still, try `three.async = false` before `three.src = .....`

Comment: I added `three.async = false;` and `script.async = false;` before `appendChild`ing each `script` and it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Yeah, was a long shot, sorry